# Should I aim to write as little as possible in my main() function?

Tags: c++, oop, program-entry-point

I'm making a small game and I don't know whether I should have the majority of the statements in the main function or instead just put them as void functions in my `player` object (I'm not really returning anything other than boolean values throughout each iteration).

Comment: 1. Very opinion based. 2. Depends on lots of factors and so too little information given.

Comment: Aim to write as much (or little) as makes sense in each function. That generally won't mean nearly everything being done in `main`.

Comment: You should aim to decompose your program into meaningful components. If some code implements something that a player does then it belongs in the player class, else it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should aim for your `main()` to be a bridge between the execution environment (the OS) and the system that you implement. This means that `main` should "crack" the command-line parameters, and then promptly pass control to the method that instantiates top-level objects and runs your system.